# styling several DIVs the same but only working on one DIV

Tags: css, html

I styled a DIV using CSS on one of my pages. 
The CSS looked think this:

```
#login {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 600px;
 height: 250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #00ae00;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
     border-radius: 15px;
    Padding-top: 10px;
    text-align:center;

}
```

and it worked as desired

I then realised i wanted to same styling for a number of DIVs on other pages. So my theory was just to change the above CSS to:

```
#login, register, home {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 600px;
 height: 250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #00ae00;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
     border-radius: 15px;
    Padding-top: 10px;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Just to show you how one of my other DIVs is placed

```
    <div id="register">
    <form action='register.php' method='post'>
 <h1>Register Here:</h1>
    <h4><?php echo $message; ?></h4>
    Username:<input type='text' name='username'
                value='<?php echo $username; ?>'><br />
    Password:<input type='password' name='password'><br />
    Repeat Password:<input type='password' name = 'repeatpassword' >
    <?php echo $recaptcha_form; ?>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
    <input name ='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'>
    </form>
    <h2>Once you have registered, log in  <a href='login.php'>here!</a></h2>

    </div>
```

but it is simply not styling it at all? 
any idea?

(please bare in mind im quite new to coding!)

Comment: You have missed to give # before id selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
#login, #register, #home
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to give **`#`** before id selector.

so the actual way will be

```
#login, #register, #home
{
 // your css
}
```

You can see how to deal with multiple selector at once from 
[here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/qt/tipcssgroupsele.htm)